# How to write data in xml file that is embedded in a dll

Tags: c#, xml, resourcemanager

I have a user control in that I embedded an xml file to store emails. Now I compiled it and made a single dll. Now I'm using this user control in a windows form and I need to write the data in that embedded xml file on a click of the button. I easily can access the data from embedded xml file by using

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(Resource.EmailHistory);
 var email=doc.Root.Elements().Select(x => x.Element("Email"));
 foreach (string item in email)
 {
      textBox1.Text+= item;
 }
```

but facing the problem while writing into the embedded xml file. please help me with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Xml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
   <Email>
       Hello
   </Email>
   <Email>
       There
   </Email>
</root>
```

Comment: _"write the data in that embedded xml file"_ - you can't.

Comment: And this has what to do with WCF?

Comment: Why don't you just write the emails into a local XML file other than the embedded XML file. Is there any security concerns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write the data into an embedded XML file, because it's a resource embedded in the DLL (or an executable).

You can potentially *replace* it by creating an entire new resource, and then using [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This isn't as simple as it sounds; you have to do all of the following (see [Updating Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources) at MSDN for details):

1. Use LoadLibrary  to load the executable file Hand.exe.
2. Use  FindResource and LoadResource to locate and load the dialog box resource.
3. Use LockResource to retrieve a pointer to the dialog box resource data.
4. Use BeginUpdateResource to open an update handle to Foot.exe.
5. Use UpdateResource to copy the dialog box resource from Hand.exe to Foot.exe.
6. Use EndUpdateResource to complete the update.

Having to do this much work just to update an XML file should tell you that you're going about it the wrong way, and that an embedded resource isn't the proper approach. (An external file or a database (which would allow a lot more information to be stored, and could be sorted, filtered, and searched) would be a much better solution, for instance.)